# Deserialization when java program is restarted

Tags: java, deserialization

I wrote two simple Junit test cases, one to serailize and another to deserialize. When I ran two test cases simultaneously deserialization worked  and gave me correct output of stored value that is 20. BUT when I ran test cases one by one ( or you can start a program and serialize and then start a  program just to deserialize ) I get different hashcode and different stored value that is 10.

```
public class SerializedSingletonClass implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 10L;

private int value = 10;

private static class SingletonHolder{
    private static SerializedSingletonClass ref = new SerializedSingletonClass();
}

public static SerializedSingletonClass getObject() {
    return SingletonHolder.ref;
}

public Object readResolve() {
    return SingletonHolder.ref;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}   
}
```

My Test cases to be run one at a time ( like you start to serialize and then again start to deserialize)

```
public void breakingSingleton_of_SerializedSingletonClass_with_serialization() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(
                    "serialized.ser"));
    SerializedSingletonClass ref = SerializedSingletonClass.getObject();
    ref.setValue(20);
    oos.writeObject(ref);
    System.out.println(ref.hashCode());
    oos.close();
    }
```

Deserialize test case

```
@Test
public void test() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(
                    "serialized.ser"));

    SerializedSingletonClass ref2 = (SerializedSingletonClass) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    System.out.println(ref2.hashCode());
    System.out.println(ref2.getValue());

}
```

Output: I get different hashcode and value as 10.

Question : How to properly deserialize ?

Comment: You're not implementing a stable hashCode() override, so Java is using the default, which is based on the location of the object when it is created (https://srvaroa.github.io/jvm/java/openjdk/biased-locking/2017/01/30/hashCode.html). If you want a stable hash code, you have to define it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the hascode insight. and for the deserialization i found the culprit. The problem was readResolve(), I came to know that when you provide readResolve() it acts on instance just created by serialization. So in my case I suspect since on second run there was no instance created it creates one and assign a value 10 then deserialize it with value 10. Removing readResolve() solved the issue.